# How to add a specific value from table to the new column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a "Order Table" . 
And In "Order Table", there is a mulpurposed Column called "Unit".

```
OrderCode,   ProductCode,   ProductName,   Unit,   ProductId
123,         002,           Box No,        1,      1111
123,         223344,        Abc,           4,      11873993
123,         888444,        Zxc,           1,      66474833
123,         883372,        Ubn,           2,      88575744
123,         002,           Box No,        2,      1111
123,         788665,        Muq,           3,      88887777
123,         900223,        Zue,           1,      22234567
123,         665543,        Erv,           1,      12399998
```

"Unit" Column has a value 1 to N for **box-numbers** for specific value Where ProductID=1111. Also "Unit" Column has **unit values** *for other ProductIDs*.

Every Order starts ProductID=1111 And First box-number = 1 (shows in the Unit field)
The below Products are in the same box until next ProductID=1111 then box-number = N (Shows in the Unit field)

Unit field shows the quantity of Products except ProductID=1111

I tried:

```
CASE WHEN ProductId = 1111 THEN Unit END AS BoxNo
```

But it doesn't work.

I wanted to add a new column called "BoxNo" which inludes for each Products box-numbers

```
OrderCode,   BoxNo,    ProductCode,   ProductName,   Unit,   ProductId
123,         Null,     002,           Box No,        1,      1111
123,         1,        223344,        Abc,           4,      11873993
123,         1,        888444,        Zxc,           1,      66474833
123,         1,        883372,        Ubn,           2,      88575744
123,         Null,     002,           Box No,        2,      1111
123,         2,        788665,        Muq,           3,      88887777
123,         2,        900223,        Zue,           1,      22234567
123,         2,        665543,        Erv,           1,      12399998
```

Comment: I don't see any way to generate the box number numerical sequence you want.  What are the rules for knowing when it should be incremented?

Comment: You results seem to assume an ordering of the table.  However, no column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Dear Gordon I also  added to the table an ID column.. (for ordering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results seem to assume an ordering in the table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column to specify the ordering.

With such a column, you an do this using window functions and logic for the `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when ProductId <> 1111
             then count(*) filter (where ProductId = 1111) over (order by <ordering col>)
        end) as box_num
from t;
```

This counts the number of 1111s up to each row.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, you would use `SUM(CASE)`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when ProductId <> 1111
             then sum(case when ProductId = 1111 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by <ordering col>)
        end) as box_num
from t;
```

Comment: Dear Gordon , What is "filter" .. ms-sql is giving error.

Comment: Dear Gordon I also  added to the table an ID column.. (for ordering)

Comment: @Claud . . . `filter` is standard SQL that MS SQL does not support.  But your question is not tagged for MS SQL.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Your Ms-sql code worked... Excellent solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but you need some script function, not just plain SQL.

Your objective from how the data is structured is to take the orders, and determine the box number. The ProductID = 1111 stands for "a new box" where to put the things of the order. Such as a package.

Fact is, you have to store a local variable to increase your value and by increasing it, you can then print it as output.

Your SQL CASE works, but doesn't provide the result you are expecting simply because it's conditioned to give "unit" in the corresponding row, like so:
[image: sets the box number as unit just if product id equals 1111]

Just by adjusting it in this way, you would have, which gives back null just on the rows with `productid` equal `1111`:

```
(CASE productid WHEN 1111 THEN null ELSE 1 END) AS boxno
```

With the result:
[image: null printed as box no if product id equals 1111]

But i guess it really depends on database you are using if there's some difference.

As test I created a simple table with the data provided in PostGreSQL, but the fact still stands as stated above.. you have no way to store a local variable unless you script it.

One work around you can use, is to use the `id` of the current row to determine which result you should consider, and stack it with a `count()`.

[image: simple select with the result of the script inserted above]

Again this has been achieved in PostGreSQL ( pgAdmin 4 ), by using this query:

```
SELECT ordercode,(CASE 
        WHEN productid = 1111 THEN null ELSE
        (SELECT count(productid) FROM test_stck WHERE productid = 1111 AND id < a.id)
        END) AS,
        productcode,productname,unit,productid
FROM test_stck AS a
```

But you have to have a ID of the row you can access, otherwise you cannot make it. Also I didn't use it, but you should be ordering your ID list as you extract it. Otherwise you could have a different sorting which would lead to unwanted results.

Another subquery that might do the trick is this:

```
SELECT ordercode,(CASE 
        WHEN productid = 1111 THEN null ELSE
        (SELECT unit FROM test_stck WHERE productid = 1111 AND id < a.id ORDER BY unit DESC LIMIT 1)
        END) AS boxno,
        productcode,productname,unit,productid
FROM test_stck AS a
```

The order by unit, implies you sort it, before extracting it. And the limit 1 ensures you select just the last element of the subquery, also the `id < a.id` is some sort of insurance.

Just to visualize the subquery complete set ( without the limit 1 ), it would be this and ordered like in this way:
[image]

I hope i didn't make it too difficult ))

Comment: @Claud what exactly didn't work? Update of add infos to your initial question so we can help you out.